# how to send data via a toggle button in a list view android

Tags: android, listview, android-togglebutton

so I'm pretty new to list views in android and android as a whole also. the issue I'm currently facing is that I have a toggle button on each item a list View, this toggle is changed to either on or off  depending what it reads from the server.

Now my issue is that I don't know how or even where to begin in making that toggle button click-able for each of the list-view items that then send the new status of the button and the device ID (the idea being it would turn a light on or off)

I'll post my code below.If you need anything else please ask. I've been stuck on this for about a week and it's driving me nuts!

this is my main activity which pulls the JSONarray of items to put into the view

```
package mmu.tom.linkedviewproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "ShowDevice";
    private ListView GetAllDevicesListView;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(TAG, "  OPened this");

        ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button_new);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Class ourClass;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i;
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceDetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setListAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
        this.GetAllDevicesListView.setAdapter((new GetAllDeviceListViewAdapter(jsonArray, this)));
    }

    private class GetAllDevicesTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray> {
        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
            // it is executed on Background thread
            return params[0].GetAllDevicesState();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
         setListAdapter(jsonArray);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is where I set up and create how the items will look and is essentially my list view adapter.

```
package mmu.tom.linkedviewproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Tom on 08/02/2016.
 */

public class GetAllDeviceListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private JSONArray dataArray;
    private Activity activity;
    private String state;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public GetAllDeviceListViewAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, Activity a) {
        this.dataArray = jsonArray;
        this.activity = a;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.dataArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // set up the convert view if it's null
        ListCell cell;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_all_devices_list_view_cell,null);
            cell = new ListCell();
            cell.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            cell.deviceId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_id);
            cell.type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            cell.toggleButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
            cell.typeImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_type);
            convertView.setTag(cell);
        } else {
            cell = (ListCell) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // changes the cell data here

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
            cell.deviceName.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            cell.deviceId.setText(" " + jsonObject.getString("deviceID"));
            cell.type.setText(" " + jsonObject.getString("type"));

            String toggle = jsonObject.getString("currentState");
            if (toggle.equals("on")) {
                cell.toggleButton.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                cell.toggleButton.setChecked(false);
            }

            String device = jsonObject.getString("type");
            if (device.equals("Light")) {
                cell.typeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_lights_on);
            } else if (device.equals("Lock")) {
                cell.typeImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_lock_open_black_24dp);
            }
            // remember to set the image to type in future
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ListCell {
        private TextView deviceName;
        private TextView deviceId;
        private TextView type;
        private ImageView typeImg;
        private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you are looking for this.

```
cell.ToggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked)
            {
                //your action
            }
            else
            {
               //your action
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've seen that a few times but I'm not sure where it goes, I've tried putting it in the list view adapter but it just throws weird errors, any idea where to put it?

Comment: you have to put inside the getView() method of adapter.. tell me the errors that you are getting

Comment: which part sorry, in the if statement or the try catch?

Comment: try outside if-else and try-catch, just before return convertView.. First try to print something or some toast to check if it is functional or not

Comment: When i do that it doesn't seem to find the toggle button listener you gave me, i get the same logs with and without the code

Comment: EDIT nevermind i got that working, now i just need to figure out how to send to send the device_ID and the position to the server

Comment: are you able to get the device id? and the position?

Comment: yeah they also print out to the samer screen

Comment: Honestly I'm just new and don't know to how to send those two pieces of data to the server (sorry)

Comment: Ok, then you should read.. If nothing helps, I can send you the code

Comment: would you still be open to helping me with this i'm really stuck on how to send the data